# Some questions about position in html

Tags: html, css, floating-point, positioning

How would be possible to do something similitar with this with pure html/css, of putting two words onde under another on the side of a big word? (i know it's possible with boostrap grid system but i want to know with pure html), furthermore, doing that and being able to move the three words down or up freely?

furthermore, how would one do to get an element to go inside of one another? (because some fonts have some large borders on it, and then you can't make another words close to each other because of this border)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with multiple `div` and a flexbox and encapsulating them into a container div. I also added `align-items: center;` to keep them centered while side by side. Look what I did here:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.bigword {
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="smallcontainer">
    <div class="smallword">Small1</div>
    <div class="smallword">Small2</div>
  </div>
<div class="bigword">BigWord</div>
</div>
```